# Angular scope property not accessible from directive in attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller like this:

```
var exampleController = function($scope, $stateParams){
    $scope.myVariable = $stateParams.id;
    console.log($scope.myVariable);
}
```

and a directive like:

```
var exampleDirective = function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            myVariable: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "myTemplate.html",
        link: function($scope){
               console.log($scope.myVariable);
        });
     };
}
```

in my html like:

```
<my-example myVariable="myVariable"></my-example>
```

Given the id in the url is 21, I got this:

```
21
undefiend
```

Do anybody know why I couldn't pass any $stateParams value so that the directive don't see it?

I've tried to pass a static value but it didn't worked too.
Tried in this way within the controller:

```
$scope.myVariable = 26;
```

Comment: `myVariable` != `my-variable` Its a typo you missed the hyphen notation there on the view. i.e `<my-example my-variable="myVariable"></my-example>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the Angular convention for attribute names:

```
<my-example my-variable="myVariable"></my-example>
```